# Over ride the labs function for second legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend

```
plot <- ggplot(data2, mapping = aes(x=Long, y=Lat) ) +
     stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon", colour="white") + labs(color = "Levels of Concentrations") +
     geom_point(data, mapping = aes(x = Long, y = Lat,colour = as.factor(TAXON_NAME))) + 
     scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "D") + labs(color = "Diptera Family Records")  + ggtitle("2015-2020 Data for England")
```

plot

I have used other questions on here and tried creating a plot then adding another plot as suggested but get the same problem:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=Long, y=Lat) ) + stat_density_2d(data2, geom = "polygon", contour = TRUE, mapping =
                                       aes(fill = after_stat(level)), colour = "black",
                                     bins = 5) +
     scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
     theme_classic() + labs(color = "Levels of Concentrations")

plot2 <- plot1 + geom_point(data, mapping = aes(x = Long, y = Lat,colour = as.factor(TAXON_NAME))) + 
 scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "D") + labs(color = "Diptera Family Records") + ggtitle("2015-2020 Data for England")
```

Is the problem to do with ..level..? I am a novice coder so unsure of the best way to fix this, sorry. I am unable to share the data as its split across  a range of sheets.

[plot without second legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt8jl.jpg)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. In your second plot you have both a `color` and a `fill` scale but added only a title for `color` via `labs()`. If you want to set the title for the fill scale then use `labs(..., fill = ...)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.